# Python list comprehension => Ruby select / reject on index rather than element

Tags: arrays, ruby

Given:

```
arr=[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
      0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8    9    # index of arr
```

In Python, one can select or reject elements of a list given the index of that element by combining `enumerate` and an `if` clause in a list comprehension:

Every item except the third:

```
>>> [e for i,e in enumerate(arr) if i%3]
[20, 30, 50, 60, 80, 90]
```

Every third item in a list:

```
>>> [e for i,e in enumerate(arr) if not i%3]
[10, 40, 70, 100]
```

Or, even easier, with a slice:

```
>>> arr[::3]
[10, 40, 70, 100]
```

In Ruby, we have [.select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) and [.reject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject)

```
> arr.each_with_index.reject { |e,i| i%3==0 }
=> [[20, 1], [30, 2], [50, 4], [60, 5], [80, 7], [90, 8]]
> arr.each_with_index.select { |e,i| i%3==0 }
=> [[10, 0], [40, 3], [70, 6], [100, 9]]
```

And then apply [.collect](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-collect) to that:

```
> arr.each_with_index.select { |e,i| i%3==0 }.collect{|e,i| e}
=> [10, 40, 70, 100]
```

For the slice, the *rough* Ruby equivalent might be:

```
> (0..arr.length).step(3).each { |e| p arr[e] }
10
40
70
100
=> 0..10
```

But I can't figure out how toe collect those into a new array other than:

```
> new_arr=[]
=> []
> (0..arr.length).step(3).each { |e| new_arr.push(arr[e]) }
=> 0..10
> new_arr
=> [10, 40, 70, 100]
```

Questions:

1. Are these the best Ruby idioms for what I am trying to do (.select or .reject with .collect)?
2. Is there a way to do something along these lines with a slice:
    
    `new_arr=(0..arr.length).step(3).each { |e| arr[e] }.some_method`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method order is relevant:

```
arr.each_with_index.select { |e, i| i % 3 == 0 }
#=> [[10, 0], [40, 3], [70, 6], [100, 9]]
```

versus:

```
arr.select.each_with_index { |e, i| i % 3 == 0 }
#=> [10, 40, 70, 100]
```

Since `select` returns an enumerator, you could also use [`Enumerator#with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index):

```
arr.select.with_index { |e, i| i % 3 == 0 }
#=> [10, 40, 70, 100]
```

Regarding your slice equivalent, you can use `map` (or its alias `collect`) to collect the items in an array:

```
(0..arr.length).step(3).map { |e| arr[e] }
#=> [10, 40, 70, 100]
```

or [`values_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-values_at) to fetch the items at the given indices:

```
arr.values_at(*(0..arr.length).step(3))
#=> [10, 40, 70, 100]
```

`*` turns the argument into an array (via `to_a`) and then into an argument list, i.e.:

```
arr.values_at(*(0..arr.length).step(3))
arr.values_at(*(0..arr.length).step(3).to_a)
arr.values_at(*[0, 3, 6, 9])
arr.values_at(0, 3, 6, 9)
```

Slightly shorter:

```
arr.values_at(*0.step(arr.size, 3))
#=> [10, 40, 70, 100]
```

Comment: Ha! It *never* occurred to me to reverse `arr.each_with_index.select` to `arr.select.each_with_index` Thanks for this answer. It will add to the googleable knowledge base of those learning Ruby who know Python.

Comment: Lovely answer, as usual.

Comment: Question: If I have `[1,2,3,3,3,2,1].select.with_index {|e,i| i if e==2}` it prints `[2,2]` rather than the expected list of indexes of `2` which would be `[1,5]`. Do you know why?

Comment: @dawg because `Array#select` returns elements, not indices. If you have a reference to the array (i.e. a variable), you could use `ary.each_index.select { |i| ary[i] == 2 }`. Otherwise `[1,2,3,3,3,2,1].each_with_index.select { |e, i| e == 2 }.map(&:last)` would work.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `each_slice` to iterate over the `arr` and to get the elements "in threes", using `each_slice(3)`:

```
p arr.each_slice(3).to_a
# => [[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90], [100]]
```

So, having that array you can see that each first element is an element in the output you want to get, so you can use `map` and to get the first element:

```
arr = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
p arr.each_slice(3).map(&:first)
# => [10, 40, 70, 100]
```

You could do it as `.map{|e| e.first}`, or `.map{|e| e[0]}`, but for a shorter version you can use just `.map(&:first)`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Also very helpful for a Ruby newbie.

Answer (score 1):

"But I can't figure out how to collect those into a new array other than(...)"
There is a method which does that, and you found its name while formulating your question:

```
arr=[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
new_arr = (0..arr.length).step(3).collect { |e|  arr[e] }
```

[collect](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-collect) has an alias: `map` .